# How to highlight an email link in SwiftUI Text with String variable

Tags: swiftui

This code:

```
Text("Email us at mail@mail.com")
```

Gives me this result:

[image: What I need]

But this:

```
let str = "Email us at mail@mail.com"
Text(str)
```

Gives me:

[image: what I don't need]

I actually will have a string like:

```
let str = "Email us at \(email)"
Text(str)
```

How can I make the email a highlighted link?

Comment: `AttributedString` w/ markdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upd, wrote this code:

```
let mail = "mail@mail.com"
let str = "Email us at \(mail)"
            
Text( (try? AttributedString(markdown: str)) ?? AttributedString(str) )
```